# <a href="javascript:viewDocument('122', '212');"> is not accessible. I am not sure why the link is not clickable

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display: block;">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <a href="javascript:viewDocument('122', '212');">
     View Document
    </a>
   <td>
  <tr> 
 </table>
</div>
```

I am not able to click the a tag which opens up a document. Sometime it worked when I used

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//a[contains(. = 'View Document')]))
```

But is is not working all the time. And I would also like to know is there any way to run the javascript in the href directly?
I already tired using Javascript Executor.

I am getting this error:- The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.

Comment: You want to select view document

Comment: //a[contains(. = 'View Document')] it is invalid dear

Comment: your xpath not locate element in my browser

Comment: I would suggest that you run it several times until it fails and then investigate. Come back and post the error in your question along with the results of your research and we can help if you haven't figured it out already.

Comment: Error:- The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

use this xpath it is working

```
 //a[contains(text(),'View')]
```

it works for me

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'View')]")).click();
```

Possibly you try to search an element when page is changed thats why you got stale error, you have to come back on sape page to locate it. I have create a demo for it. First click the link and come to main page again click and navigate then no error is occurred.

```
for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'View')]")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.navigate().back();
    }
```

Comment: I am able to access the element using xpath. Xpath has no problem. But I am not able to click the element sometime. I am not sure what is the problem.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath(//a[contains(. = 'View Document')])).click() this correct way

Comment: You can use wait with ElementisnotClickable metod

Comment: I added waitForElementToLoad and then checked the element using optionalElementExists, it returns true. And then added a Thread.sleep(5000). And still not able to click the button

Comment: You can use my xpath once and try to run program 5 times and check when it fails , then we can decide some conclusion

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155272/discussion-between-iamsankalp89-and-maninder-singh).